# How can I force a fileName using contentService?

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a script that gets a user list with a few parameters (group, type of data dump) and works as a service.

It uses [contentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/?hl=fr-FR) to return data as CSV.

Everything works fine except that in Chrome (Mac OS) or Firefox (Mac OS) it always saves the file instead of showing it on screen... (File name: echo.csv)

Using Safari I get the data on screen.

My question is: **Can I change that default name** without using the [forced downloadAsFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/text-output?hl=fr-FR#downloadAsFile%28String%29) method?

The script is used to serve content to a PHP app that we develop on another server. (I'm not really involved in that part of the development, I just do the Google Apps Script part. :-)

Here is the script:

```
function doGet(e) {
  if(e.parameter.log!='adminUser'){return ContentService.createTextOutput("erreur de logging, vous n'êtes pas autorisé à voir ce résultat, contactez Serge @ insas").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT)};
  var cat = e.parameter.cat;
  var type = e.parameter.type
  Logger.log(cat)
  var ssGroup = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AnZ5_ShBzIxxxxxxxxx2MkZPNVViNXc');
  var ssUser = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AnZ5_ShBzI6pdGxxxxxxxxxxxxxyNGoxRmc');
  var shU = ssUser.getSheetByName('Feuille de travail principale')
  var shG = ssGroup.getSheetByName('Horizontal')
  var datagroup = shG.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dataUser = shU.getDataRange().getValues();
  if(type==1){
    var outString = '';
    for(var n=0 ; n<dataUser.length ; ++n){
      if(dataUser[n][11].toString().indexOf(cat)==-1){ continue };
      var dataRow = dataUser[n][3]+','+dataUser[n][2]+','+dataUser[n][4]+','+dataUser[n][11]+';\n';
      outString+=dataRow
    }
    Logger.log('part1'+outString);
    var result = ContentService.createTextOutput(outString).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.CSV);
    return result;
  }else{
    var outString = '';  
    for(var n=0 ; n<datagroup.length ; ++n){
      if(datagroup[n][0].toString().indexOf(cat)==-1){ continue };
      var dataRow = datagroup[n][0];
      for(var c=2;c<datagroup[n].length;++c){
        if(datagroup[n][c]!=''){
          dataRow+=(','+datagroup[n][c])
        }else{
          dataRow+=';\n';
          break;
        }
      }
      outString+=dataRow
    }
    Logger.log('part2'+outString);
    var result = ContentService.createTextOutput(outString).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.CSV);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to view a CSV in the browser, you don't need to be honest... just say it's TEXT.

```
function doGet(e) {
  // &type=TEXT to view as text
  var type = (e.parameter['type'] && e.parameter['type'] == "TEXT") ? "TEXT" : "CSV";

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheets()[0];
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var outString = '';
  for(var row=0 ; row<data.length ; ++row){
    outString += data[row].join(',') + ';\n';
  }
  Logger.log(outString);

  var result = ContentService
                   .createTextOutput(outString)
                   .setMimeType( ContentService.MimeType[type] );
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! glad to know you encourage me to lie... ;-)  just a small question : what is the `eval` for in `setMimeType(eval( 'ContentService.MimeType.'+type))`

Comment: That `eval()` is a wonderful piece of Javascript magic. Given a string, it evaluates it as code. It's there because in an earlier iteration I was passing the entire `ContentService.MimeType.TEXT`, and `eval` would select the correct type. Really, I should not have left `eval` in, instead should have used a named property, like `ContentService.MimeType[type]`.  (That's what it says in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), anyway!